# How to validate a url and a text?

Tags: javascript

In one of my textbox i need to enter only multiple url or multiple text at a time,not both.
So while i use the regular expression given below the domain name "google.com" will satisfy the condition of text.But i need to return false for this type of entry.Can anyone please suggest an idea?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("newway", function(value, element) {     
            var testarray = ['.....'];
        var url_count = 0;
        var text_count = 0;
        for(var k in testarray){

            if(/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?((([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+)|localhost)(\/[\w- .\/?%&=]*)?/i.test(testarray[k]))
            {
                console.log("url");
                url_count++;
            }
            else{
                if(/^[a-zA-Z+,:;%()]+$/.test(testarray[k])){
                    console.log("text");
                    text_count++;
                }
            }
        }
        if((url_count==0 && text_count > 0) || (url_count >0 &&  text_count == 0)){
            if((url_count==testarray.length) || (text_count==testarray.length)){
                return true
            }
            else{
                return false
            }

        }else{
            return false
        }       

}, "Please enter url or text");
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem -- please tell us about X

Comment: If you're sure you have to avoid text that _looks like_ a partial URL then simply add a 2nd regex for text, if it passes first one then it must **do not** pass second one. In that regex just check for malformed/partial URLs (like google.com or www.google.com without protocol prefix). I said "if you're sure" because it's possible that a valid text may look like an url (for example because user did forget to add a proper space after a dot).

Comment: Thanks Adriano,for the suggestion